# Full list of Erc20 Tokens

Tags: blockchain, tokens

Is there a way to get a full and updated list of all Erc20 tokens on the Ethereum blockchain?
[Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/tokens) contains a token name search, but it doesn't show the full list, which is 7668.

[image]

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: Nop, no luck until now.

Comment: When you say "list", what do you need the list to contain? Contract addresses? Other information?

Comment: If it is because you want to see whether or not to transfer an ERC20 token to an Ethereum wallet etherscan is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

I have found two lists:

- CoinMarketCap's tokens tab: https://coinmarketcap.com/tokens/views/all/
- Eidoo's list: https://eidoo.io/erc20-tokens-list/

Etherscan shows (as of 10/02/2018) 37k tokens. I'm not sure there's a list which references them all.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at open source directory of ERC20 token images.

- Request token images by the contract address.
- Supported over 380 ERC20 contracts at the moment (most popular)
- Minimum 128x128 resolution (high quality)

Github for all details: https://github.com/TrustWallet/tokens

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/blockchain-etl/ethereum-etl.

`bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.tokens` in google bigQuery

Answer (score 0):

State of the DAPPS has the most comprehensive list I know -
https://www.stateofthedapps.com/

Answer (score 0):

this should work, full list below:
https://etherscan.io/tokens

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't the full list.

Answer (score 0):

here is one: https://github.com/ethereum-lists/tokens/tree/master/tokens/eth

Sadly it's not comprehensive.  Did you manage to find a better one?